# Dot product with nabla

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

It has come up in my studies that nabla dotted with a vector field is the divergence. However, when studying vorticity I have recently seen w . nabla, where the nabla second. Is this still divergence or does it mean something else?

Comment: Vorticity has more to do with rotation. Hard to tell what exactly you have recently seen. A bit more details would be of great help.

Comment: I was taught the vorticity equation Dw/Dt = (w . nabla)u

Comment: Where $\omega$ is the [Vorticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) which is the rotation of the flow velocity $\vec{u}$. If you still have questions please include more definitions and use MathJax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of $A. \nabla $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858286/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-nabla)